# Sharing Common objects - warning "defined but not used"

Tags: c++, oop, coding-style

I have a number of C++ classes, alot of them (not all) share two "static size variables" e.g.

share.h

```
/*Other variables in this header used by all classes*/ 

static size width=10;//Used by about 60% 

static size height = 12;//used by about 60%
```

So I placed them in a header file along with other objects that all classes share.

when I compile the project I get alot of warnings (from the classes which dont use these), which complain about them being defined and not used. But I need them there!

So I ask, is there a way to define these, so that classes not using these two variables can use this header file without throwing warnings about them not being defined?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The warning you are seeing is just telling you the variables are just not being used.  It's nothing to worry about really.  Just a point though, not all warnings should be ignored.

Comment: No i guess. Use a seperate header file for these static common variables if you dont want those warnings

Comment: I see, but is there a way to define them in this header, so that classes needing them can call them, and the classes that dont, wont? like some sort of a hash or global method? namespace? sorry im not very good with this :)

Comment: @Perl_noob: It's a _warning_. By definition, it is not an error; it isn't _wrong_ to do it. The compiler is just letting you know something that _could_ be broken.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either declare them `const`, or declare them `extern` and define them in exactly one source file. A compiler should expect constants to be defined (in header files) but not used, and not give a warning for that.

Defining static variables that you don't use is often a sign of an error, so the warning is useful in that case. (If you actually do want separate, modifiable copies of these variables in multiple translation units, then you should probably rethink your program design).

Comment: Is the C++ compiler really supposed to make a distinction between header/included source code files and others?

Comment: @Alex: No, I don't believe I said anything like that. This warning comes from declaring a `static`, non-`const` variable, and not using it. Doing that is often an indication that it should either be `const` or `extern`, or not exist at all, so the warning is usually useful.

Comment: I inferred that possibility from "A compiler should expect constants to be defined in header files but not used, and not give a warning for that."

Comment: @Alex: OK, perhaps some extra punctuation will make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 13):

The warning doesn't say that they aren't being defined. The warning specifically says that they are being defined, but not *used*. That is, you asked for something, but then you didn't use it.

Your real problem is the fact that these are `static` global variables. This means that each .c or .cpp file that includes the header will have *it's own copy* of that variable.

So if you have `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` that include `share.h`, `a.cpp` can change `width` to 20, but `b.cpp` *cannot* see the effect of that change. That's why the compiler issues a warning. Because if you declare a `static size width` in a file, and don't use it in *that particular* file, then you certainly can't be using it *anywhere else*. And that's suspicious behavior, to define a variable that you never use.

In general, you should never put global `static` variables in a header. If you want constant values, you should declare them as such:

```
const size width=10;//Used by about 60% 
const size height = 12;//Used by about 60%
```

If you don't want them to be constant, then you should declare them in a header with `extern` (without initializing them), then pick *one* .cpp file and define them (without `extern`, but with a value). As follows:

```
//share.h
extern size width;
extern size height;

//share.cpp
size width = 10;
size height = 12;
```

Comment: I see what you are saying and thank you so much for helping to paint a much cleaner picture :) can I jusy add, I was wanting to try to cut down the lines of code, I feel that a seperate header to decalrre these, then to define them again in each class that requires them just seems a bit..well..wasteful? is there no other way?

Comment: @Perl_noob: If you're doing the `extern` trick, you don't define them in each .cpp file. That would lead to multiple definitions at link time. You define them in _one_ .cpp file. Which one is up to you. It's exactly like how you put the prototypes for functions in header files that many include, but only put the implementation in one .cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the const qualifier, not static. The meaning of static is totally different from your intent. You can find more information about static here http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html.